# During email delivery, how do MTA, MDA, POP/IMAP connect with each other?

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot, mail-transport-agent

I have already read [Why use Dovecot AND Postfix/Sendmail?](https://serverfault.com/questions/626803/why-use-dovecot-and-postfix-sendmail), [Why use both Dovecot and Postfix?](https://serverfault.com/questions/716653/why-use-both-dovecot-and-postfix), [Why use both Dovecot and Postfix?](https://superuser.com/questions/962074/why-use-both-dovecot-and-postfix) which give the general idea, but here I'm looking for more precise details to understand how email servers connect together.

Let's say I own the domain `example.com` with DNS configured like this:

```
example.com       MX     mail.example.com
mail.example.com  A      1.2.3.4
```

and `postfix` and `dovecot` are intalled on my Debian server of IP 1.2.3.4.

Let's say I send an email:

- from my ISP address `johndoe@myisp.com`, from my local computer Thunderbird
- ... to the address `johndoe@example.com`

**What is the big picture of the different connections that will happen during this process?**

Is the following correct:

1. My local computer connects to `smtp.myisp.com` (port 25 or 587)
2. My ISP's SMTP server (postfix?) queries the DNS of `example.com` and eventually will connect to `mail.example.com`, i.e. my own server where `postfix` is listening on port 25 or 587
3. My server's `postfix` saves the email on disk (where, by default?)
4. or `postfix` sends the email to `dovecot` (how do they connect together?)
5. When eventually I want to fetch mail on `johndoe@example.com` with another Thunderbird account,  the computer will connect my server 1.2.3.4 on port 110 or 995 (POP3).

?

In this case, `postfix` is the MTA, `dovecot` is the POP3/IMAP server, but what is the MDA/LDA (Delivery Agent)?

Comment: That's most likely a question for https://serverfault.com/ not unix.se.

Comment: @Basj It does seem like there's no specific UNIX/Linux question here; would you like to move this question to SF?

Comment: @Artem if you think the question belongs on SF, I'm curious why you answered it here?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I'm specifically speaking about a setup in Debian machines, using `postconf`, etc. thus I posted here, but I agree it is located at the intersection of these different sites.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Since it hasn't been moved yet I thought I could as well answer right here. Suit yourself, you may as well delete the answer if it prevents it from moving.

Comment: @Basj the question is quite generic - these MTA/MDA servers are present in most Linux distros.

Comment: Since it's using software on a Debian system, I'm OK with leaving it here. If you have further questions along the general mail transport line, please consider SF; if it goes towards specific configuration of the MTA/MDA, then I think U&L is appropriate. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you @JeffSchaller! If you have more details about where the MTA passes information to the MDA in my question's example context (johndoe@myisp.com sending an email to johndoe@mydomain.com), an additional answer on this specific point would be very interesting :) I don't exactly see where the MTA and MDA differ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. That depends on how your SMTP client is set up but in general that's correct.
2. Correct.
3. Let's talk about qmail-compatible maildirs as no one really uses `/var/mail/username` UNIX-style mailboxes any longer (too many disadvantages, barely any advantages). Emails are stored where you specify your Maildir is, by "default" it's

```
sudo postconf -e "home_mailbox = Maildir/"
```

4. By default `postfix` doesn't send emails to anyone or anything, it just stores them using the built-in delivery agent. There's no communication between `dovecot` and `postfix` per se AFAIK.
5. You connect to `dovecot`, and it allows you to work with the user qmail-compatible maildir specified above, e.g.

```
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
```

> In this case, postfix is the MTA, dovecot is the POP3/IMAP server, but what is the MDA/LDA (Delivery Agent)?

Postfix again: http://www.postfix.org/OVERVIEW.html : `man 8 local`.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Last thing: in 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., where is the MDA/LDA? I don't really see where the MTA and MDA differ, can you add precisions about this?